Ledger Application level error (sign-with-hash): Unknown status code 0x5515
Ever since upgrading my baking ledger to use version 2.4.7 of the baking app, my baker runs for only few minutes before erroring every attestation with this message:
Ledger Application level error (sign-with-hash): Unknown status code 0x5515

In that state, the octez-client show ledger command no longer finds the ledger. When I unlock the ledger with the PIN, it's already in the baking app and attestation starts working again. I've seen this both on a Nano S and Nano S+ ledger.

It sounds as though the device is locking. To use the new baking app, you need to do the following in the ledger device settings:

enable screen saver
disable global PIN lock

You should ensure that you have uninstalled the wallet application before starting to bake for additional security. It's worth noting, however, that you cannot exit the baking app without entering your pin.
For more details, see the Baking app REAMDE - particularly Step 3.
